# How to calculate the average by multiple keys using a tool like d3.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, d3.js

I have an array of objects:

```
var array_x = [
  {'src': '9', 'tgt': '2', 'key_a': value_1}, 
  {'src': '9', 'tgt': '2', 'key_a': value_2},
  {'src': '9', 'tgt': '5', 'key_a': value_3},
  {'src': '9', 'tgt': '5', 'key_a': value_4},
  {'src': '6', 'tgt': '1',  'key_a': value_5}, 
  ]
```

How can I group elements of this array that have the same `src` **and** the same `tgt` values in order to get the average of `var_a` (like below):

list 1

- src: 9
- tgt: 2
- average:  (value_1+value_1)/2

list 2

- src: 9
- tgt: 2
- average:  (value_3+value_4)/2

list 3

- src: 6
- tgt: 1
- average:  value_5

How can I achieve this with D3.js or any other js tools?

**EDIT 1**
*value_1*, *value_2* ... are integer variables, not strings!

Comment: do you want a new array with the averages?

Comment: Yes, exactly :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could collect all groups in an object and map the averages.

```js
var array = [{ src: '9', tgt: '2', key_a: 1 }, { src: '9', tgt: '2', key_a: 2 }, { src: '9', tgt: '5', key_a: 3 }, { src: '9', tgt: '5', key_a: 4 }, { src: '6', tgt: '1', key_a: 5 }],
    averages = Object
        .values(array.reduce(function (r, o) {
            var key = ['src', 'tgt'].map(k => o[k]).join('|');

            r[key] = r[key] || { src: o.src, tgt: o.tgt, count: 0, sum: 0 };
            r[key].sum += o.key_a;
            r[key].count++;
            return r;
        }, {}))
        .map(({ src, tgt, count, sum }) => ({ src, tgt, average: sum / count }));

console.log(averages);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Good point about this: `o.key_a.match(/\d+$/)[0]` Actually,  I don't know if the Op wants that.  Let's see.

Comment: Thank you, but it seems I'm not giving a clear problem description, "value_1", "value_2" ... are integer variables, not strings, Sorry.

Comment: Amazing solution! Thank you @Nina

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this alternative using the functions `reduce` and `map`.

*Group by combination of `src` and `tgt`.*

```js
var array_x = [{'src': '9', 'tgt': '2', 'key_a': 2}, {'src': '9', 'tgt': '2', 'key_a': 3},{'src': '9', 'tgt': '5', 'key_a': 2},{'src': '9', 'tgt': '5', 'key_a': 4},{'src': '6', 'tgt': '1',  'key_a': 3}, ]

var result = Object.values(array_x.reduce((a, c) => {
  var groupKeyBuilder = (target) => target.map(s => c[s]).join('||');
  var groupKey = groupKeyBuilder(['src', 'tgt']);
  
  if (a[groupKey]) {
    a[groupKey].average += Number(c.key_a);
    a[groupKey].count++;
  } else {
    a[groupKey] = {count: 1, average: Number(c.tgt), src: c.src, tgt: Number(c.tgt)};
  }
  
  return a;
}, {})).map(({average, src, tgt, count}) => ({ src, tgt, average: average / count }));

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: at the end ... it looks similar.

Comment: it is easy to extend the keys array with more keys for grouping.